# How to minimize a group of combined buttons (icon of the same application) on taskbar?

Tags: windows-7

I want to minimize a group of combined button but not sure how to do it. Trying <kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd> when click on the group doesn't work. Anyone get an work-around for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 7 Hold the SHIFT key and then right click on the Stack of combined taskbar items and you will see the old XP list of options including the Minimize All Windows and Restore All Windows options.

Answer (score 0):

Use ctrl+click to select the items you want, this "Groups" them, then right-click on any of the selected items, and select "Minimize Group". Works on XP-Vista.. not sure about 7.

Comment: Even for XP/Vista, I'm not sure I get what you do to get the group minimized. Where exactly do you do the 'ctrl+click'? I guess you click on a group (a list of windows/items is showed) and 'ctrl-click' on the items - doing this just show the selected item.

Comment: Hold down the CTRL key, then left click on the taskbar items you want to group, now, you can either release or keep holding ctrl, and you right-click on any of the now grouped items, you will see a different menu than if you had simply right-clicked on an individual item, this one will include "Minimise Group", Show Stacked, Show Side-by-Side and Cascade and Close Group.

Otherwise, I guess I might have misinterpreted what you meant by "combined button"

Comment: Holding `shift` key and right click work for me